# Not able to check accurately if the value in state matches a certain string

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-state, react-native-voice

I am trying to make a react native app in which I want to check if the user pronounced the word/words correctly or not. For this task, I am using react-native-voice library and the user's speech is converted into text using it and the results are stored in presults (useState).
But I do not know how and where in the code I should put the if else condition to check if the text in presults match the required string and display the message accordingly.

Here's  the code App.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

import Voice from 'react-native-voice';

const App = () => {

   const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [presults, setPartialResults] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    //Setting callbacks for the process status
    Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
   Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = onSpeechPartialResults;
 

    return () => {
      //destroy the process after switching the screen
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    };
  }, []);

  const onSpeechStart = (e) => {
    //Invoked when .start() is called without error
    console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);

  };

  const onSpeechEnd = (e) => {
    
    console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
    //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer stops recognition
    
  
  };

  const onSpeechError = (e) => {
    //Invoked when an error occurs.
    console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
    setError(JSON.stringify(e.error));
  };

  

  const onSpeechPartialResults = (e) => {
    //Invoked when any results are computed
    console.log('onSpeechPartialResults: ', e);
    setPartialResults(e.value);
   
  };


  const startRecognizing = async () => {
    //Starts listening for speech for a specific locale
    try {
      await Voice.start('tr-TURKEY');
      setError('');
     setPartialResults('');
      
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  


  const destroyRecognizer = async () => {
    //Destroys the current SpeechRecognizer instance
    try {
      await Voice.destroy();
      setError('');
     setPartialResults('');
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
          Speech to Text Conversion in React Native |
          Voice Recognition
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          Press mike to start Recognition
        </Text>
      
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
         
          <Text style={styles.textWithSpaceStyle}>
            {`Error: \n ${error}`}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {startRecognizing();}}>
          <Image
            style={styles.imageButton}
            source={{
              uri:          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/microphone.png',
            }}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          Partial Results
        </Text>
              <Text
                style={styles.textStyle}>
                {presults}
              </Text>
            
      <View style={styles.horizontalView}>
         
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={destroyRecognizer}
            style={styles.buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>
              Cancel
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I put the if else condition in onSpeechEnd function,but the results are not accurate. Here's the modified onSpeechEnd function:

```
const onSpeechEnd = (e) => {
    if(presults == 'tamam'){
      Alert.alert('c','c');
      console.log('c');
    }
      else {
        Alert.alert('w','w');
        console.log('w');
      }
    
    console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
    //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer stops recognition
    
  
  };
```

and here's the console result:

```
 LOG  onSpeechStart:  {"error": false}
 LOG  onSpeechStart:  {"error": false}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": ["Merhaba"]}
 LOG  w
 LOG  onSpeechEnd:  {"error": false}
 LOG  onSpeechStart:  {"error": false}
 LOG  onSpeechStart:  {"error": false}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": ["tamam"]}
 LOG  w
 LOG  onSpeechEnd:  {"error": false}
 LOG  onSpeechStart:  {"error": false}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Root Case**

The below line from the `log`

```
LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": ["tamam"]}
```

which is the result of:

```
console.log('onSpeechPartialResults: ', e);
```

suggests that `e` is an object which has one prop `value`. This prop has a value which is an array: `["tamam"]`.

The line used to store this info is:

```
setPartialResults(e.value);
```

So `presults` will be an `Array`. Now, the `if` tries to compare a string `"tamam"` with the array: `["tamam"]` and since these do not match, it executes the log from the `else` part (ie, `w`).

**Solution**

While this may be handled in a number of ways, the below is what comes to mind as being quick, simple.

Please try the below `if` statement in a separate `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('presults changed to: ', presults);
  if(presults.includes('tamam')) {
    console.log('c');
  } else {
    console.log('w');
  }
}, [presults]);
```

This will check for the presence of the `'okay'` (ie, `tamam`) in the `presults` array. So, `tamam` will evaluate to truthy, while the `'hi'` (`merhaba`) will still evaluate to falsy. Since this `if-else` is placed within a separate `useEffect` (with dependency array being set to `presults`), it will execute when `presults` changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still executing the else part even after I changed the if condition

Comment: Hmm. In that case, let us investigate why. Would you please add to `onSpeechEnd` a `console.log('presults at onSpeechEnd bgn: ', presults);`. Let us see what is the value populated in `presults` when `onSpeechEnd` starts executing.

Comment: ops! there's no value in presults at the beginning of onSpeechEnd. Following is the console output:

Comment: LOG  onSpeechStart:  {"error": false}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": [""]}
 LOG  onSpeechPartialResults:  {"value": ["tamam"]}
 LOG  presults at onSpeechEnd bgn:
 LOG  onSpeechEnd:  {"error": false}

Comment: Answer has been edited. Please see **_`Please try the below if statement in a separate useEffect`_** in the answer.